No module named ‘torch._custom_ops’ in Jupyter Notebooks
I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask, but I just installed cuda tools to run some GPU-based machine learning stuff on my computer, and I'm running into an issue importing torch.
I'm on Ubuntu 22.04
I've tried installing torch within a conda environment and locally. Unfortunately, when I try to import torch into a jupyter notebook, I get the error (Doing literally nothing else in the notebook but importing torch):
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch._custom_ops'; 'torch' is not a package

When I run nvcc -V my output is:
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2024 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Mar_28_02:18:24_PDT_2024
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.4, V12.4.131
Build cuda_12.4.r12.4/compiler.34097967_0


When I run nvidia-smi my output is:
NVIDIA-SMI 550.67                 Driver Version: 550.67         CUDA Version: 12.4 

I have an NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti.
Based on Table 3 of https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html, CUDA 12.4 seems like the right version for my NVIDIA driver.
I'm able to run python3 -c 'import torch' with no output, which I assume is good news.
That being said, when I try to import torch into a jupyter notebook, I get the error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch._custom_ops'; 'torch' is not a package

I was able to find torch._custom_ops myself, so I know it exists, but I'm not sure why it isn't working in Jupyter Notebook?
I found this: Loading a pretrained model from torch.hub in Sagemaker but that didn't seem relevant given I'm not using Sagemaker and simply trying to get my local machine ready to tackle GPU training tasks.
I see other posts such as No module named "Torch"
pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.0.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl, which I haven't done, but looks like it's for windows. Is that something I need?
I would appreciate any help, insight, or simply comments telling me a better place to be asking this question.
Thank you

Thanks for responding :) That first link you posted leads to your personal profile. Also, I have a pip environment (not conda). I tried adding
%pip install -c torch torchvision torchaudio
to my notebook to no avail (getting the error ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'torch') and magic %pip3 wasn't found either

"I was able to find torch._custom_ops myself, so I know it exists, but I'm not sure why it isn't working in Jupyter Notebook?" Things like this usually mean you installed it somewhere on the system; however, not in the place Jupyter is looking. I gave some advice for a different package here yesterday. You can probably combine that with some more specific, yet older advice ....

 here.

"%pip install -c torch torchvision torchaudio"???? You are mixing and matching in the wrong way. -c torch comes from conda setting the torch channel. The two package managers have different syntax. You want to start with %pip install torch based on here. Then looks like pip install torchvision maybe. However, I know you are saying you are using pip here. And it may work given pip is listed here; however, pip cannot work at the level of doing things to your computer that Anaconda/conda can. Since ...

Should I be using conda instead of pip then? I tried %pip install torch and get a long list of "Requirements already satisfied" which makes sense because I have torch on my local machine and am running the notebook locally as well. Thanks for being patient Wayne

 you want to do GPU stuff that involves hardware, pip may not be to do enough on your system to get you there. Be aware thought that using the Anaconda Distribution/conda adds another layer for your to learn to use it correctly. You'll want to read the Getting Started if you go that route.

It sounds like that's what your suggestion is :) I'll try that and let you know how it goes. Thanks Wayne

If torch was installed correctly then importing it should not give you an error. When you say you import it you don't provide what you actually do to try that leads to that error ModuleNotFoundError: ... 'torch' is not a package? You should update your post to include that.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

This is just a version issue...I did
!pip install torch==1.4 torchvision==0.14.1

and it seems to work fine!
